# invalid use of void expression error in vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, functor

in below  code snippet, I am not sure why i am getting error like "invalid use of void expression" while executing
function object with vector. eventhough it is valid outside vector.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

class AddVal {
  int i;
public:
  AddVal (int a) : i(a) {}
  void operator()(int val) {
    cout << i + val << endl;
  }
  void operator()(string obj) {
    cout << "string obj" << obj;
  }
};

int main() {
  vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3 };
  vector<string> vecs = { "mo", "han", "raj" };
  int x = 2;
  AddVal(2)("john"); // valid
  AddVal(1)(2);      // valid
//for_each(vecs.begin(), vecs.end(), AddVal(2)("john")); // not valid
  for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), AddVal(x));           // valid
  // not valid in vector (invalid use of void expression)
//for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), AddVal(1)(x));

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from `for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), AddVal(1)(x));`? According to type of `AddVal::operator()`, `AddVal(1)(x)` returns `void` which cannot be used in expression.

Comment: The suspected line will end up in calling `void operator ()( int val)`, which results as `void`, and doesn't work with the context. Did you mean to use a return type and `return i + val;` instead of `cout`????

Comment: it just sums up the vector element with 2. my question is without vector it doesn't flash the error but with vector i am getting this error. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what for_each actually expects as input: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

As third parameter you want to send in a function pointer or functor. In your *invalid* cases you are sending in the return value of `void AddVal::operator()(int)` or `void AddVal::operator()(string)` (which is void).

In your *valid* case you are sending in an object of class AddVal i.e. a function object.

Comment: AddVal(1)(x) is valid but not in for_each. that is my question . functor has been used as a third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `AddVal(1)` is an object - you're calling the constructor.

This object has a (well, two) `operator ()` member functions; one taking an int, the other taking a string.

`AddVal(1)(2)` is the result of calling `operator ()(int)` on the object `AddVal(1)`, 
and since `AddVal::operator()(int)` returns void, that is the type of `AddVal(1)(2)`.